# Cannot enable 4X MSAA Anti-Aliasing in DirectX 11

Tags: directx, directx11, antialiasing

I am currently learning how to use DirectX11 but I am unable to use 4X MSAA. Here is my code (Since I'm just learning I haven't used any headers or classes, sorry for the messy code) If anybody can point out what I need to do or fix that would be great.

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

using namespace DirectX;

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer;    // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11Buffer* triangleVertBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS;
ID3D10Blob* VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob* PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* vertLayout;

                                       // function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitScene(void);

                            // the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, 800, 600 };
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass",
        L"Eagle Engine (Alpha)",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 2;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode
                                                            // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &devcon);

    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, NULL);

    ID3D11Texture2D* pDepthStencil = NULL;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
    descDepth.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    descDepth.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
    hr = dev->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &pDepthStencil);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
    descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    // Create the depth stencil view
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDSV;
    hr = dev->CreateDepthStencilView(pDepthStencil, // Depth stencil texture
        &descDSV, // Depth stencil desc
        &pDSV);  // [out] Depth stencil view

    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, pDSV);


    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
    InitScene();
}

// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->Draw(3, 0);
    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    // close and release all existing COM objects
    swapchain->Release();
    dev->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    devcon->Release();
    triangleVertBuffer->Release();
    VS->Release();
    PS->Release();
    VS_Buffer->Release();
    PS_Buffer->Release();
    vertLayout->Release();
}

struct Vertex 
{
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z)
        : pos(x, y, z) {}
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
};

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

void InitScene()
{
    //Compile Shaders from shader file
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);

    //Create the Shader Objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    //Set Vertex and Pixel Shaders
    devcon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);

    //Create the vertex buffer
    Vertex v[] =
    {
        Vertex(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f),
        Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
        Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f),
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));

    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 3;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;

    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData));
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &triangleVertBuffer);

    //Set the vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &triangleVertBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    //Create the Input Layout
    dev->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
        VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);

    //Set the Input Layout
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

    //Set Primitive Topology
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
}
```

When I compile the code above this is what I get. Notice the jagged edges although I put the multisample count as 4X? (If you can't see the jagged edges view it in fullscreen)

[image]

I have tried the following

```
// fill the swap chain description struct
scd.BufferCount = 2;                                    // one back buffer
scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
UINT maxQuality;
hr = dev->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(scd.BufferDesc.Format, scd.SampleDesc.Count, &maxQuality);
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = maxQuality;
scd.Windowed = TRUE;
scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;     // allow full-screen switching// windowed/full-screen mode
                                                        // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct

HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &scd,
    &swapchain,
    &dev,
    NULL,
    &devcon);
```

But I get the error `Identifier 'hr' is undefined`.

Comment: Please define your hr variable before the first call (write the HRESULT hr = E_FAIL before the call to Checkmultisamplequalitylevels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sample quality should be greater than 0. You can check the maximum supported quality by calling the ID3D11Device::CheckMultisampleQualityLevels method. For example:

```
HRESULT hr;
UINT maxQuality;
hr = dev->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(scd.BufferDesc.Format,scd.SampleDesc.Count,&maxQuality);
```

If `hr == S_OK` when the function returns, the maximum supported quality level will be written into maxQuality variable. You can then add this line to the swapchain desc:

```
scd.SampleDesc.Quality = maxQuality; // or something less than maxQuality
```

Also provide the quality to the depth stencil descriptor:

```
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = scd.SampleDesc.Quality;
```

Your depth stencil texture should also be declared as multisampled. This is done by the following line:

`descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D`;

That should be `D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS`

Comment: I did what you said but I still do not get anti aliasing to work. I think I am meant to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476499(v=vs.85).aspx for my device.sampledesc.quality. Could you show me how to use this?

Comment: Sure, please see my update :)

Comment: I tried that but I ran into another problem :(, see my edit (I don't know how to reply to an answer)